# Pass Account ID Using URLFOR

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, urlfor

I have a Visualforce Page that uses the standard Contact controller with a controller extension. The page is embedded on the Contact record layout and displays a related list of a custom object that has a master-detail to the Contact and Account records.

I am trying to create a custom button on the embedded VF page to create a new record that pre-populates the associated Contact and Account (from the Contact) IDs to 2 lookup fields on the custom object record. I am using a CommandButton with !URLFOR($Action attributes to open the new record creation page (in Lightning), however, I cannot figure out how to get the Account pre-populated and then redirect back to the contact record once saved.

The line below opens the pop-up and pre-populated the Contact ID, but I need to select the Account and then it directs to the new record created, not the original Contact record.  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with a CommandButton?

```
<div style="margin-left: 30%;">
    
    <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.VIP_Type__c.New,null,[VIP_Type__c.ContactId = Contact.Id])}" value="New VIP Type" oncomplete="window.open('/{!Contact.Id}&retURL=(!Contact.Id}')" reRender="frm"/>
    
</div>
```

Comment: URLFOR has four args, the third arg are parameters to pass to the page being opened; also, your onComplete is missing the `!` after the `{`

Comment: Thanks @cropredy.  I added the ! to my onComplete, but it had no effect on the re-direct.

Comment: I also updated my command button above. The ContactID pre-populates, but when I try to add a 2nd variable to pre-populate (Contact.AccountId) I get an error "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.AccountId"  Any idea why that is happening? I am querying AccountId in my controller.

Comment: you need to add an `<apex:variable>` for Contact.AccountId so the controller can bind to that variable

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the line to:

            <div style="margin-left: 30%;"><apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.VIP_Type__c.New,null,[retURL={!con.Id}, VIP_Type__c.ContactId = {!con.Id}, VIP_Type__c.AccountId = {!con.AccountId}])}" value="New VIP Type" /></div>
 and it gives me a syntax error, but no detail on what.

Comment: Remove all the {! and } for the Params within the URLFOR third arg